# JAXB EclipseLink problem with marshalling CHOICE with nillable elements

Tags: null, jaxb, eclipselink, marshalling

I have a schema defined as this:

```xml
<complexType name="x">
    <sequence>
        <element name="year" type="date"/>
            <choice>
                <element name="comuneNascita" type="string" nillable="true"/>
                <element name="statoNascita" type="string" nillable="true"/>
             </choice>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

When I try to marshall the class generated with xjc ( with xjc:simple option ) and I get this result:

```xml
[...]
<statoNascita xsi:nil="true"/>
<comuneNascita>xxx</comuneNascita>
[...]
```

Removing nillable="true" solve this problem but then I have to specify a valid element ( not nilled ).

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid your problem by having a property annotated as follows:

```
@XmlElements({
   @XmlElement(name="comuneNascita", type=String.class),
   @XmlElement(name="statoNascita", type=String.class),
})
```

You can get XJC to generate a property annotated as above using a JAXB bindings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          version="2.1">
    <globalBindings choiceContentProperty="true"/>
</bindings>
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html

Comment: This is only true if you don't use already the option  <xjc:simple/> to avoid JaxElement type generation for some attributes. In that case the option choiceContentProperty="true"  it is ignored.
To avoid this problem I had to change the schema as this:
<choice minOccurs="0">
 <element name="comuneNascita" type="string"/>
 <element name="statoNascita" type="string"/>
</choice>
so the elements when null are not marshaled with xsi:nil. But somethimes to change the schema it's not an option.